# Basic question from a beginner. Problem with definitions in a bucle. Maple

Tags: for-loop, maple

Let's suppose we are in this case (I'm using Maple)

```
add:=function()
e1:=0;
e2:=1;
for j in [1..2]do
ej:=ej+1
od;
return e1,e2;
end;
```

This program gives me a global variable error. I understand why that happens -- because `ej` is not defined as local -- but if you define it then the program just doesn't do anything. ) I don't know how to solve it. **My objective (in a bigger program) is to call `e1,e2` in a `for` loop.**

Maybe I didn't express myself correctly simplifying my problem, there is my Program, **it is made with program GAP** but it works similar to Maple:

```
G12Decode:=function(c)
localx,G,C,sG,sH,a,u,b1,e1,b2,e2,b3,e3,b4,e4,b5,e5,b6,e6,h1,h2,i,j; 
x:=Codeword(c,GF(3));
G:=[[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,2,2,1], 
[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,2],[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,1,0,1,2], 
[0,0,0,0,1,0,1,2,2,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,1,0]];
C:=GeneratorMatCode(G,GF(3));
sG:=x*TransposedMat(GeneratorMat(C));
sH:=x*TransposedMat(CheckMat(C));
a:=[0,0,0,0,0,0];
b1:=Codeword([0,1,1,1,1,1],GF(3)); 
e1:=Codeword([1,0,0,0,0,0],GF(3));
b2:=Codeword([1,0,1,2,2,1],GF(3)); 
e2:=Codeword([0,1,0,0,0,0],GF(3));
b3:=Codeword([1,1,0,1,2,2],GF(3)); 
e3:=Codeword([0,0,1,0,0,0],GF(3));
b4:=Codeword([1,2,1,0,1,2],GF(3)); 
e4:=Codeword([0,0,0,1,0,0],GF(3));
b5:=Codeword([1,2,2,1,0,1],GF(3)); 
e5:=Codeword([0,0,0,0,1,0],GF(3));
b6:=Codeword([1,1,2,2,1,0],GF(3)); 
e6:=Codeword([0,0,0,0,0,1],GF(3));

if Weight(sH)<=2 then
sH:=ShallowCopy(VectorCodeword(sH));
Append(a,sH);
a:=Codeword(a,GF(3));
u:=x-a;
return u;
elif Weight(sG)<=2 then
sG:=ShallowCopy(VectorCodeword(sG));
Append(sG,a);
sG:=Codeword(sG,GF(3));
u:=x-sG;
return u;
else
for i in [1..6] do
for j in [1..6] do
if sG-bi=ej or sG-bi=2*ej then 
h1:=sG-bi;
h2:=ei;
h1:=ShallowCopy(VectorCodeword(h1));
h2:=ShallowCopy(VectorCodeword(h2));
Append(h1,h2);
h1:=Codeword(h1,GF(3));
u:=x-h1;
return u;
elif sG-2*bi=ej or sG-2*bi=2*ej then
h1:=sG-2*bi;
h2:=ei;
h1:=ShallowCopy(VectorCodeword(h1));
h2:=ShallowCopy(VectorCodeword(h2));
Append(h1,h2);
h1:=Codeword(h1,GF(3));
u:=x-h1;
return u;
fi;
od;
od;
fi;
end;
```

The program dont send me an error but i know it don't work because of the ej,bi and ei. I want to do what it says after the last "else" but i don't know how to solve it to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for wasting my time by tagging this `maple` when in fact it's all about a GAP program. No, they do not work the same. There are *some* similarities in language syntax, but nobody with Maple only could run this. Anyway, is it really true that in GAP you can reference `bi` or `ej` and magically get values for `b3` and `e4` if `i=3` and `j=4` as values for the loop index?!? It sounds doubtful.  Perhaps GAP allows you to concatenate names. Or perhaps you could instead declare `b` and `e` as arrays (similar to `a` above?), and then store/reference in `b[i]`, `e[j]`, etc.

Comment: @acer Sorry about that. But your answer about Maple also was necessary because I'm also working on it. Anyways, I tried what u said and it worked, thank you. And sorry again about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid. It is **proc**, not **function**.

And **add** is already a Maple command, so it's a protected name and cannot be assigned to. You have to use another name.

And your syntax for the do-loop is likely not what you want. You probably want **for j from 1 to 2 do** .

And you really should initialize **ej** with a value before doing the recursive assignment **ej:=ej+1** .

And you might as well declare the procedure's **local** variables.

Personally, I favour using **end do** instead of **od** , and **end proc** instead of just **end** , in modern Maple. It makes it easier to tell what's being terminated.

For example,

```
restart;

my_add:=proc()
  local e1,e2,ej,j;
  e1:=0;
  e2:=1;
  ej:=0;
  for j from 1 to 5 do
    ej:=ej+1
  end do;
  return ej,e1,e2;
end proc:

my_add();

                 5, 0, 1
```

There is a [Maple Programming Guide](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ProgrammingGuide/Contents), which you can read online or inside Maple's own Help system. It has a nice [introduction to writing procedures](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=ProgrammingGuide%2FChapter01#bookmark24). And there is a more detailed Help page for the [proc](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=procedure) command.

Comment: I added things in the question. Sorry for not explaine it properly before.